# I'm trying to use apollo graphql subscriptions with my react-native app. Works fine on android but on iOS there is no response

Tags: react-native, websocket, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-ws

Here is my `graphqlClient.ts` file:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  concat,
  Operation,
  NextLink,
  FetchResult,
  Observable,
  split,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import auth, { FirebaseAuthTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import Config from 'react-native-config';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: Config.BE_BASE_URL });

import { GraphQLWsLink } from '@apollo/client/link/subscriptions';
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: 'ws://my-gqlserver.railway.app/graphql',
  }),
);

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink(
  (operation: Operation, forward: NextLink): Observable<FetchResult> => {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      (async () => {
        const currentUser: FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null = auth().currentUser;
        const token = currentUser ? await currentUser.getIdToken(false) : null;
        operation.setContext({
          headers: {
            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
          },
        });
        return forward(operation).subscribe({
          next: observer.next.bind(observer),
          error: observer.error.bind(observer),
          complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
        });
      })();
    });
  },
);

const graphQLClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: concat(authMiddleware, splitLink),
});

export default graphQLClient;
```

Here is the query:

```
export const SUBSCRIBE_TO_LOCATIONS = gql`
  subscription Subscription {
    locations
  }
`;
```

And on Home screen I'using `useSubscription` hook from `@apollo/client`

`HomeScreen.tsx`:

```
import { useSubscription, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { SUBSCRIBE_TO_LOCATIONS } from '../graphql/queries';

  const { data: subscriptionData, loading: subscritionLoading } =
    useSubscription(SUBSCRIBE_TO_LOCATIONS, {
      onData: subData => {
        console.log('onData', subData);
      },
    });

  console.log(subscriptionData, 'subscriptionData'); 
  //  iOS ==> undefined subscriptionData
 //   android ==> array of coordinates
```

I'm doing everything from the official docs, and for websocekt protocols I'm using `graphql-ws` because `subscriptions-transport-ws` is deprecated, as mentioned in docs.

I'm pretty sure everything is connected well because on android works how it should, so my guess is there is something elese I need to configure on ios but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this came late but i had a similar issue recently;

Change this

```
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: 'ws://my-gqlserver.railway.app/graphql',
  }),
);
```

to this

```
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: 'wss://my-gqlserver.railway.app/graphql',
  }),
);
```

Basically we are changing the insecure `ws://` to the secure `wss://` . iOS doesn't allow loading from insecure links on either `http` or `ws` as opposed to `https` or `wss`. You could override this behaviour by editing info.plist's transport security key (or something like that) but i am guessing you are on Expo's managed workflow and it might be hard to do this except you eject or switch to the bare workflow.

Cheers.